# Why ui router iterates in resolve function by utf-8 url prarams ( in some browsers)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, phantomjs, httprequest

I have a route like this:

```
  $stateProvider.state('show', {
    url:   "/page/:uuid/:title",
    views: {
      "":       {
        templateUrl: ThemePrefix + '/views/ShowCase.html',
        controller:  'ShowCtrl',
        resolve:     {
          ShowDate: function (SearchRequests, $stateParams) {
            // This will send http request depended on uuid param
            return SearchRequests.GetExtend($stateParams.uuid);
          }
        }
      },
      "footer": {
        templateUrl: ThemePrefix + '/views/footer.html',
        controller:  'FooterCtrl',
        resolve:     {
          Popularareas: function (WebServices) {
            // This will send another http request
            return WebServices.GetPopularAreas();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

The `title` param in url, can be a Persian word, separated by `-`.

*(e.g. `domain.com/page/53f198db0fdf0/مثال-با-فاصله`)*

In some browsers like `phantomjs`, the router's resolve function will iterate which causes this log: `Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations` and multiple requests to server!

But it's work normally on chrome, firefox, and etc.

**P.S:** The controller specified in route *(in example above `ShowCtrl`)*, would not execute at all in this situation.

Comment: hi Behzadsh i have this problem to , do you solved it yeat?